# Is there a way to disable multi-editing in Notepad++ v8.6?

Tags: notepad++

I want to be able to hold down CTRL so I can just type "V" on multiple lines to paste the same thing over and over. This was how Notepad++ behaved before I updated to 8.6. Now, if I am still holding down the CTRL key, it will continue to paste in all the places that I have previously pasted.

This is due to the new Multi-Editing feature, which I would strongly prefer to be turned off. Unfortunately, the OFF switch does not seem to be present (at least in v8.6). Is there possibly a hidden configuration file where I can change this setting?

I checked in Notepad++'s `Settings -> Preferences -> Editing`, but there wasn't anything there pertaining to multi-editing.

Comment: There is a discution about that on [Npp community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/25207/npp-8-6-multi-edit-preference-not-shown)

Comment: @Toto Thanks, I saw that. Unfortunately, there is no solution posted so far.

Answer (score 3):

Multi-edit is the main feature of [Npp 8.6](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/v86-20thyearanniversary/)

[image: Multi-edit]

But, as illustrated in [this discussion](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/25207/npp-8-6-multi-edit-preference-not-shown/2) and in [`notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus` issue 14464](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14464), it results in unexpected behavior during copy-paste.

Dec. 13th, 2023: [issue 14464](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14464#event-11230506690) and [14296](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14296#issuecomment-1852403388) mentioned below refer to a fix: [PR 14476](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/14476)

> In order to disable the "`Column to multi-select`" ability (new feature introduced in v8.6), users must add an empty file named "`noColumnToMultiSelect.xml`", in "`%APPDATA%\Notepad++`" directory (or in the Notepad++ installed directory in portable mode) to prevent this behaviour.

---

Original answer (beginning Dec. 2023)

From [the issue](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14464#issuecomment-1847854397), the OP notes:

> It seems that <kbd>Esc</kbd> only works if I move the cursor up or down after some vertical editing (e.g. adding some indent spaces) and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. So that seems like a bug.

Before, [the manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/#multi-editing) included:

> Whether or not you can use Multi-Editing mode is determined by the `Settings > Preferences > Editing > ☑ Enable Multi-Editing (Ctrl+Mouse click/selection)` checkbox: with it checkmarked, Ctrl+Click will add caret locations; with it not checkmarked, Multi-Editing is disabled.

For now, maybe a [NppPythonScript](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript) could disable the feature. Though [class `MULTIPASTE`](https://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/enums.html#multipaste) perhaps?

Or you could try and find the `shortcuts.xml` file. It is usually located in the Notepad++ installation folder or in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++`. Look for the `<InternalCommands>` section. Find the entry related to multi-editing or the Ctrl key function you wish to modify. Comment out or modify the specific shortcut setting.

---

[Randy Fellmy (`Coises`)](https://github.com/Coises), creator of [ColumnsPlusPlus](https://github.com/Coises/ColumnsPlusPlus) (a plugin for Notepad++ which offers features for working with text and data arranged in columns), [adds](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14464#issuecomment-1848611444):

> Based on [Issue #14266](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14266), it appears this behavior is by design. What I believe will always work in 8.6 is to press an arrow key, and *then* press the Escape key.
>
> This is annoying for people who use rectangular selections often but rarely if ever use stream multi-selection. Pressing an arrow key is a pretty routine behavior which will take some retraining of “muscle memory” to replace, for no gain at all.

See [commit aef043](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/aef04381800c920264dc475483f5013572dfea5a) (not yet released).

You can try it with the executable found on the [PR page](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/14476/checks#:%7E:text=fb7c01e-,Artifacts,-10).

[image: https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/62826272/290428716-a8206da3-43fa-400b-b59f-3ccdacc1656f.png?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.qqDcF2Ah363gdl8VYVkVLophdRVMlmSAKEW-TZZXAhU]

---

[PR 14513](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/14513) adds:

> ### Make "line copy/cut/delete while no selection" optional
>
> By adding disableLineCopyCutDelete.xml in "`%APPDATA%\Notepad++`" directory (or in the Notepad++ installed directory in portable mode) to:
>
> - prevent hard coded <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd> shortcut deletes whole line while no selection.
> - prevent Copy command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) copies whole line (without selection).
> - prevent Cut command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>) cuts whole line (without selection).
> - add SCI_CUT (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>), SCI_COPY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>INS</kbd>) & SCI_PASTE (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>INS</kbd>) shortcuts
>
> Note: the old disableHardCodedShiftDelete.xml (of [53b5055](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/53b5055118caa5934b535c5521f04f991c13143b)) is canceled, the new `disableLineCopyCutDelete.xml` is used instead.

Comment: I really do appreciate the highly detailed response. Unfortunately, I haven't had much luck. The only thing I have yet to try is using the [NppPythonScript](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript), because I don't know how to use it, what it is, or how it would specifically help me. And the `shortcuts.xml` noticeably didn't change at all from 8.5 to 8.6. I ran it through a comparer just to be sure (I had a backup from 8.5.). It was definitely a good idea to check, though.

Comment: In response to your latest edit (2023-12-10), I can see how that would be beneficial to some people, but in my case, I am trying to avoid additional key presses. So, pressing escape isn't necessarily good for me, as letting go of the `CTRL` key before I click, and pressing the `CTRL` key again would have the same effect.

Comment: @Caleb I agree. I am trying to document what I can find so far on this topic. [Don HO ](https://github.com/donho) has [assigned your ticket to himself](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14464#event-11201303925): let's wait for any feedback.

Comment: @Caleb [PR 14476](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/14476) might help. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that fix doesn't seem to work at all. I followed the steps very carefully and restarted Notepad++. (I also tried the same thing in Program Files/Notepad++, but this didn't do anything either)

Comment: @Caleb it will, this is for the next release of notepad++.

Comment: @Caleb I have edited the answer to make that clear, and to reference the commit which will fix this.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help with this. Looks like I'll be waiting for that to release :)

Comment: @Caleb I have edited the answer to include the executable for notepad++, which would allow you to test that new option, while waiting for a new release.